# Scalaz pipe operator connected with a list method

Tags: scala

I am a newbie to `Scala`, but I have some experience in using `OCaml`. I am thinking to adopt the pipe operator defined in `Scalaz` in the following way:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def test = {
  def length2(x:String) = List(x.length * 2)
  "asdasd" |> length2
}
```

The above code works fine. However, when I want to bridge another function to get the length of the `list`, it throws an compilation error:

```
def test = {
  def length2(x:String) = List(x.length * 2)
  "asdasd" |> length2
  .length    <======== I cannot do this...
}
```

Besides, can I put the `|>` operator in another line? like this?

```
def test = {
  def length2(x:String) = List(x.length * 2)
  "asdasd" 
  |> length2          <====== I cannot do this... 
}
```

Currently, I have no idea how to do the above two things in `Scala`. I am really sorry if this question is too naive.. But could anyone tell me whether it is feasible in `Scala`? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the "thrush" combinator a function, so the following works:

```
"asdf" |> length2 |> (_.length)
```

If you want to insert line breaks, put the operator at the end of the line:

```
"asdf" |>
length2 |>
(_.length)
```

or the following is also valid:

```
"asdf"
.|> (length2)
.|> (_.length)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since Scala 2.13, a `pipe` method is provided by the Scala standard library:

```scala
scala 2.13.3> import scala.util.chaining._

scala 2.13.3> "asdf".pipe(length2).pipe(_.length)
val res2: Int = 1
```

To use the same method in Scala 2.11 or 2.12, add [scala-collection-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-collection-compat) as a dependency.