# Methods on `Any` for applying a function?

Tags: scala

I find myself writing Scala programs more often recently.

I like to program in a style that often uses long method chains, but sometimes the transformation you want to apply is not a method of the object you want to transform.  So I find myself defining:

```
class Better[T] (t: T){
  def xform[U](func: T => U) = func(t)
}

implicit def improve[T](t: T) = new Better(t)
```

This allows my to write the chains I want, such as

```
val content = s3.getObject(bucket, key)
                .getObjectContent
                .xform(Source.fromInputStream)
                .mkString
                .toInt
```

Is there any similar facility already in the standard library?  If so, how should I have discovered it without resorting to StackOverflow?

Comment: it's coming in Scala 2.13: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7007

Comment: @SethTisue:  The best answer so far is "No it's not in the standard library, and also you shouldn't do that".

But "It's not in the standard library as of 2.12 but will be in 2.13" is actually a more useful answer.  So if you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: (I think this should probably be closed as a duplicate, actually, because people have been asking for `|>` or `pipe` or whatever you want to call it for 10+ years, so almost certainly there's already a Q/A pair for this)

Comment: How do I close it as a duplicate?

Comment: You have to find the Q it’s a duplicate of, which I admit I was too lazy to do

Comment: I've added an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63928768/86485 that explains how to use the standard library's `pipe` method in Scala 2.13, and also how to use it in 2.12 and 2.11 (by adding a dependency on scala-collection-compat).

Answer (score 1):

It's not *the standard library*, but it might be "standard enough": with Cats, you should be able to write something like

```
val content = 
  s3
  .getObject(bucket, key)
  .getObjectContent
  .pure[Id].map(Source.fromInputStream)
  .mkString
  .toInt
```

where [`pure[Id]`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/syntax/ApplicativeIdOps.html#pure[F[_]](implicitF:cats.Applicative[F]):F[A]) wraps the input value into the do-nothing `Id` monad, and then passes it as argument to `Source.fromInputStream`.

> **EDIT**: This does not seem to work reliably. If the object already has a method `map`, then this method is called instead of `Id.map`.

Smaller example (just to demonstrate the necessary imports):

```
import cats.Id
import cats.syntax.applicative._
import cats.syntax.functor._

object Main {

  def square(x: Int) = x * x

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(42.pure[Id].map(square))
  }
}
```

---

However, writing either

```
val content = 
  Source
  .fromInputStream(
    s3
    .getObject(bucket, key)
    .getObjectContent
  )
  .mkString
  .toInt
```

or

```
val content = 
  Source
  .fromInputStream(s3.getObject(bucket, key).getObjectContent)
  .mkString
  .toInt
```

does not require any extra dependencies, and frees you both from the burden of defining otherwise useless case classes, and also from the burden of reindenting your code every time you rename either `content` or `s3`.

It also shows how the expressions are actually nested, and what depends on what - there is a reason why the vast majority of mainstream programming languages of the past 50 years have a call-stack.